# How can I change the color of a child component when clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple 'Rectangle' components in a 'Wall' that should change color when clicked. The onClick in 'Rectangle' is used in another Component that will make the 'Rectangle' hidden or not. I tried to do something similar here, but I can't change variables inside the 'Rectangle' component.

My attempt

```
customClickEvent={() =>{this.props.color = hidden_dictionary[count];}}
```

Wall.js

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    const color_dictionary = {0: "bg-red-400", 1: "bg-blue-400", 2:"bg-green-400", 3:"bg-yellow-400"};

    return (
        <div className="grid grid-flow-col grid-rows-4 lg:py-20 gap-y-1 gap-x-1 lg:gap-y-6 lg:gap-x-6 justify-center items-center">
            <Rectangle type="wall">Fiji</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Hazelnut</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Mocha</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Australia</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Cook Islands</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Cube</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Vanilla</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Butter Pecan</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">San Pellegrino</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Coconut</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Papua New Guinea</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Caramel</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Prince</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Guam</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">Champagne</Rectangle>
            <Rectangle type="wall">T</Rectangle>
        </div>  
    )
```

Rectangle.js

```
    //ANSWER
    if(props.type === "answer") {
        width = "p-2";
        height = "h-12 lg:h-20";
        text_size = "text-2xl sm:text-4xl lg:text-5xl";
    }

    //WALL
    else if (props.type === "wall")
    {
        width = "w-20 sm:w-24 lg:w-52  cursor-pointer";
        height = "h-16 sm:h-20 lg:h-40";
        text_size = "text-1xl lg:text-4xl";
        color = props.color;
    }

    //VOWELS
    else if (props.type === "vowels")
    {
        width = "p-4";
        height = "";
        text_size = "text-3xl sm:text-4xl lg:text-5xl";
        color = "bg-blue-800 text-white";
    }

    else
    {
        width = "w-16 sm:w-36 lg:w-80";
        height = "h-12 sm:h-28 lg:h-64";
        text_size = "text-2xl sm:text-6xl lg:text-8xl";
    }

    return (
      <div onClick={props.customClickEvent} className={width + " " + height + " " + props.color + " " + " shadow-2xl rounded-md " + props.hidden}>
         <h1 className={text_size + " w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center text-center"}>{props.children}</h1>
        </div>)
```

Comment: I think props are meant to be read only inside the component. You need to save `color` in state and update the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props aren’t designed to be mutable. In other words, setting a new value on  `this.props.color` won’t cause the rectangle to re-render. Even if it did, the value of `this` in your callback will be for the instance of `Wall`, because you’re using an arrow function, which inherits its `this` from the surrounding scope.

One solution would be to have your Wall component store the colour of each Rectangle as state, and pass that via the `color` prop. Your callback handler could then change the colour. However, because you have multiple `Rectangles`, you would need some way of distinguishing between them an index or perhaps ID.

If it’s not important for your `Wall` to know whether the `Rectangle` has been clicked, then it would be simpler to define the click handler inside `Rectangle` and have it modify state in the `Rectangle`, i.e:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState();

return (
<div onClick={() => setColor(‘new colour’)} className={width + " " + height + " " + color + " " + " shadow-2xl rounded-md " + props.hidden}>
         <h1 className={text_size + " w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center text-center"}>{props.children}</h1>
        </div>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried toggling the CSS class onClick ? That class would be styled according to Your needs. The only thing You have to do it do dynamically add a class.